# bootstrap not load when opening in other comp in lan (works fine in my own laptop)

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, xampp

bootstrap can't load when open web in another pc (lan), but work fine in my own computer..
here the image
in my laptop

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ULc72aD.jpg]
[image]

in other pc

[image]
[image]

what setting i need to change in xampp or apache ?
thankyou
edit : my bootstrat, etc for program in second pic

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/bootstrap.css'?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/jquery.datatables.min.css'?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<link href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css'?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'?>"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/bootstrap.js'?>"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery.datatables.min.js'?>"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js'?>"></script>
```

it works now i just need change the config , from local host, to my own ip/ make it dynamic so i don't need to change it everytime my ip change.
thx 4 all your help and answer

Comment: How do you include the bootstrap.css file? Can you show that code?

Comment: cek again bro, already edited my post and include the code

Answer (score 0):

Change your css link to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and your script links to this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

That way it will work on any system without you having to copy over all the bootstrap files every time

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a path problem. 
Please try to access your web pages by the IP (which you are using on the desktop) on your laptop. It may not work due to unable to access assets. So you need to change your path of CSS, JS, and Images.

If all things work fine on your laptop with IP then it will work on your desktop as well.

Comment: using ip in my laptop browser work fine,
when i use inspection on browser it show (in pc), 
GET http://localhost/xxxxx/xxxxxx
ER_CONNECTION_REFUSED 
i try change the way i load css,etc

Comment: replace the `localhost` with your IP in the assets link.

Comment: Welcome brother

Comment: @WisnuJatiRogoJuni, Can you please approve my answer.